# How to include js file without knowing proper name in Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

```
<script src="~/angular/runtime*"></script>
<script src="~/angular/polyfills*"></script>
<script src="~/angular/vendor*"></script>
<script src="~/angular/main*"></script>
```

[image]

I want to add these scripts in my Layout page

Comment: How have those files been built? I guess there should be an option to remove the hashes in those filenames in your javascript built pipeline

Comment: I build those files from npm through ng build --prod command

Comment: Try `ng build --outputHashing=none` or `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the hashes in your js file names are caused by the `--prod` flag in the angular-cli.

You basically have to options here:

- remove the `--prod` flag
- add `--output-hashing none` flag

That means you would end up with a build command similar to this:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

Please note, that the hashes serve a specific purpose: Cache-Busting. Everytime you generate a new build, these hashes change and if you inject the script(s) automatically into a html file using the angular-cli, this has the benefit of not needing to check if you have to clear your cache and if the changes have been picked up by your browser or if they have been served from disk.

Documentation: https://angular.io/cli/build